# Find all "1 reference" of all interfaced methods (signatures) with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm wondering... is there a way of listing all "1 reference"s of interface methods with (C#) Visual Studio (or ReSharper)?

The reason the methods have just 1 reference is because they have an implementation. Even though they have a reference, they are not really referenced by other implementations!

**Example:**

[image: References example]

So I want to find all "InterfacedMethod" kind of methods, there are no real references to these kind of methods.

Comment: You mean list all interfaces that only have 1 implementation?

Comment: No, the methods (signatures) of the interfaces....

Comment: An example would be useful.

Comment: Added an example of what I mean. I want to find all "InterfacedMethod" kind of methods, there are no real references to these kind of methods.